# Creating image gallery in wordpress

Tags: php, images, gallery

Lets assume I have two following directories fruits and vegetables under my image folder and that I want to show all images on some specific page.

My questions are following:

1. How to implement PHP script that will show all images from specific folder?
2. How can I implement to pull thumbnail and big image from same folder, and show them like
   in [photobox](http://dropthebit.com/demos/photobox/) mode, ie. once clicked on a thumbnail image, you get to big screen?

I have tried modifying following

```
<div id="partner">
        <?php 
            $temp = $wp_query; 
            $wp_query = null; 
            $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
            $wp_query->query('showposts=-1&post_type=gallery'.'&paged='.$paged); 
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
        ?>
        <!-- LOOP: Usual Post Template Stuff Here-->
            <div class="part_img_class col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <a rel="tooltip" title="<?php the_content();?>" href="
                        <?php $saved_post_id = $post->ID; ?>
                        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $saved_post_id ) ); ?>

            ">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb');?>
            </a>
            </div>
        <!-- LOOP: Usual Post Template Stuff Here-->
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php 
            $wp_query = null; 
            $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
        ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to use a plugin like nextgen-gallery?
You can ask the plugin to scan a dir to build a gallery, then are many possibilities to display the images.

If this cannot be a solution you need to access via php directly the filesystem, not difficult but some work needed ;-)